# Pfsense 2.03 slow upload rate for file transfers

Tags: pfsense

We are using an 8 Mbps connection(Wan) with an upload rate of 6 Mbps.With pfsense 2.03, the upload rate is really slow like 30 Kbps.Is there a configuration in pfsense to increase the upload speed?
Please note that we are not using any traffic shaper or some thing like that in pfsense.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a configuration to increase upload speed. Most often, if there are no limiter or traffic shaper configs in place, that's because you have a duplex mismatch. Your provider expects you to force speed and duplex and you're set to auto, or vice versa. That tends to affect upload more significantly than download. Make sure your WAN port is set how your provider expects it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling, and found this [thread](http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=46346.0;prev_next=prev)

Are you running in a VMware environment?

If so, you might want to check some of those settings  as well, I know sometimes software like PFsense wants promiscuous mode enabled or sometimes disabled, check that settings in VMware.

Comment: don't touch any of the VMware settings unless you're using CARP.